# How do you load a custom module into Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

This has been driving me nuts for a long time now. I have followed every tutorial I could find on the internet (here are couple examples[ [[1](https://gist.github.com/Youka/2a6e69584672f7cb0331)], [[2](https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/1594905#file-fun-cpp-L6)] of the maybe half dozen good ones found via Google search), and still no clear explanation. Although it seems it must be something fairly simple as that lack of a documented explanation implies that it's something most people would take for granted.

**How do I load a custom module into Lua?**

On the advice of questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575803/creating-a-c-dll-loadable-by-lua), I have written a module that builds a shared library with the expectation that I would be able to load it through a `require` call. However, when I do that I get undefined symbol errors, despite those exact symbols appearing in the list from the command `nm -g mylib.so`.

Those two tutorials I linked before aim to create executables that look wrappers of the `*.lua` file. That is, the built `*.exe` file should be called to run the Lua program with the custom module.

I understand that these types questions are asked here fairly frequently (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484773/call-c-functions-in-an-active-program-from-lua)), but I am still at a loss. I tried some of the binding packages (Luabind and OOLua), but those didn't work out great (e.g. my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712317/cant-load-shared-library-compiled-with-c-and-luabind-package-into-lua)--which I did ultimately figure out, sort of).

1. I have implemented a class in C++
2. I have wrapped the constructors, destructors, and functions with thunks
3. I have built it errorless-ly as a shared library

Yet no matter what I get `undefined symbol: ...` errors when I try to load it as `mod = require('mylib.so')`. How do I do this?

---

**Working Example of a Library of Functions**

For the record, just registering a basic function works fine. The below code, when built as `libluatest.so`, can be run in Lua using the commands:

```
> require('libluatest')
> greet()
hello world!
```

*libluatest.cpp*

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lua.h>
}

#include <iostream>

static int greet(lua_State *L)
{
    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static const luaL_reg funcs[] =
{
    { "greet", greet},
    { NULL, NULL }
};


extern "C" int luaopen_libluatest(lua_State* L) 
{
    luaL_register(L, "libluatest", funcs);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Failing Example of a Class**

This is what I am stuck on currently. It doesn't seem to want to work.

*myObj.h*

```
#include <string>
class MyObj
{
    private:
            std::string name_;

    public:
            MyObj();
            ~MyObj();

            void rename(std::string name);
};
```

*myObj.cpp*

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lua.h>
}
#include <iostream>
#include "myObj.h"

void MyObj::rename(std::string name)
{
    name_ = name;
    std::cout << "New name: " << name_ << std::endl;
}

extern "C"
{
    // Lua "constructor"
    static int lmyobj_new(lua_State* L)
    {
            MyObj ** udata = (MyObj **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(MyObj));
            *udata = new MyObj();
            luaL_getmetatable(L, "MyObj");
            lua_setmetatable(L, -1);
            return 1;
    }

    // Function to check the type of an argument
    MyObj * lcheck_myobj(lua_State* L, int n)
    {
            return *(MyObj**)luaL_checkudata(L, n, "MyObj");
    }

    // Lua "destructor": Free instance for garbage collection
    static int lmyobj_delete(lua_State* L)
    {
            MyObj * obj = lcheck_myobj(L, 1);
            delete obj;
            return 0;
    }

    static int lrename(lua_State* L)
    {
            MyObj * obj = lcheck_myobj(L, 1);
            std::string new_name = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
            obj->rename(new_name);
            return 0;
    }

    int luaopen_libmyObj(lua_State* L)
    {
            luaL_Reg funcs[] =
            {
                    { "new", lmyobj_new }, // Constructor
                    { "__gc", lmyobj_delete }, // Destructor
                    { "rename", lrename }, // Setter function
                    { NULL, NULL } // Terminating flag
            };

            luaL_register(L, "MyObj", funcs);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compiled into `libmyObj.so` using a simple CMake build with C++11 standard flags on.

**Error**

```
> require('libmyObj')
```

> error loading module 'libmyObj' from file './libmyObj.so':
>     ./libmyObj.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5MyObjC1Ev stack traceback:     [C]:
>   ?     [C]: in function 'require'  stdin:1: in main chunk  [C]: ?

---

I am dealing with Lua 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am wondering if it has something to do with the mix of C and C++...

Comment: Thanks for posting something that works, can you post something that fails, perhaps then we can see what your problem is?

Comment: @dave: Done. Perhaps unrelated, I do dislike the practice of downvoting without commentary...nobody gains that way

Comment: Could you add the exact errors you get when you compile the above failing example? Exactly which symbols are undefined?

Comment: @harmic: Added it to the OP. That symbol `_ZN5MyObjC1Ev` shows up when I run `nm -g libmyObj.so`

Comment: (Unrelated:) You want something like [`luaT_checkudata`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/lib/luaT/luaT.h#L70), at least from C. From C++ most of the Lua API has undefined behaviour and you need to be very careful.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thank you, I will look into that. Yea, sorry I deleted that other question because it seemed to be getting nowhere and only drew offense

Comment: @KerrekSB: Also, I do pass data through C, so I don't think that should be an issue but I will be aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It seems that you do not implement:

   `MyObj() ;  ~MyObj();`
2. and be careful with luaopen_* function, since module name is `myObj`, function name should be `luaopen_libmyObj`.

Comment: Whoops, to #2, that's correct. I was generalizing my filename but forgot to change that from my project's name to myObj. I have edited the OP, but that's a good note to keep in your answer regardless.